# Matrix properties and machine learning/data mining

Tags: matrix, machine-learning, data-mining, linear-algebra

I'm doing some data analysis in a Statistical Pattern Recognition course using PRML. We analyzed a lot of matrix properties, like eigenvalues, column independence, positive semi-definite matrix, etc. When we are doing, for example, linear regression, we need to calculate some of those properties, and fit them into the equation.

So my question is, my question is about the intuition behind these matrix properties, and their implications in the ML/DM literature.

I'd be really appreciated if someone can answer this question.

Comment: 1. Which properties? You named a few of them and left an *etc*. Your question is too vague.

Comment: 2. You should ask at Math.StackExchange.com or CrossValidated.StackExchange.com or DataScience.StackExchange.com. Your question doesn't seem to be related to programming, so it's an offtopic here.

Comment: This maybe off topic here at stackflow as a non-programming question. But if anyone could answer, can you teach me what is the importance of eigenvalue, positive semi-definite matrix, and column independence for ML/DM. And possibly, other important matrix properties you think important, and why. Thanks!

Comment: Also, there is plenty of information on the intuitions in Wikipedia and books. You just need to read more. But you should also study the non-matrix-based methods. This may be your missing piece: what are the benefits of doing some things in matrix form?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse. Thanks for your advice. And indeed, the question you posed is to the point. I'm doing it in matrix just because this course asks me to do this. There are more methods out there that offer different perspectives. This is very important piece of advice. I really appreciate it.